# Reduce pdf size in .Net

Tags: c#, pdf, asp.net-web-api, postscript, acrobat-sdk

I have a `pdf` template of size 230KB. In my `WebAPI` for multiple users, taking copy of that template pushing data to it, and merging using `iTextsharp` library. For 1500 users, total file size is reaching up to 320 MB.

I tried using `BitMiracle`, it reduced the file size to 160 MB. But it is still a large file.

I used `acrobat Pro` and used `Save as Other` option `Reduced Size PDF`, it reduced file size to 25 MB.

I want to decrease the file size to 25MB in my WebAPI using `C#` which will be hosted on server later.

As user is not supposed to edit that `PDF`, he will just store it as a record.  Can i generate a post script file and then use acrobat distiller to decrease the size?If yes, how can I do it?

I am using `ghostscript.Net`. Wrote this method, it is not throwing any error. But i am unable to find the path of generated postscript file

```
    public void convertToPs(string file)
    {
        try
        {
            Process printProcess = new Process();

            printProcess.StartInfo.FileName = file;
            printProcess.StartInfo.Verb = "printto";
            printProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = "\"Ghostscript PDF\"";
            printProcess.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            printProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            printProcess.Start();

            // Wait until the PostScript file is created
            try
            {
                printProcess.WaitForExit();
            }
            catch (InvalidOperationException) { }

            printProcess.Dispose();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

Please help

Comment: So you have 1500 users all writing into a single PDF? - One solution is to not do that. (i.e. generating on-demand only)

Comment: Actually WebAPI code writing to PDF. So 1500 copies being generated, merged into single PDF as output

Comment: What kind of data is pushing into the pdfs?

Comment: As it is a template, using key value pair, integer and strings getting pushed to PDF

Comment: Is there a change to reduce the size of the template (reduce images,...)?

Comment: No, we do not have any image in template.

Comment: I think without any code it is hard to help you. Please add your code and what you have tried.

Comment: Converting a PDF to PostScript has inherent risks, since the graphics model is not identical. You could try using Ghostsctript to take the PDF as an input and write a new PDF as output. That often reduces the size of files and doesn't involve a conversion to PostScript. Note that GS is licensed under the AGPL, in case that has implications for your usage. You should probably also look at Ghostscript.NET rather than Ghostscript itself, since you want to use C#

Comment: @Ben,@KenS edited the question and added my code. Help me out

Comment: I can not find generated post script file. I am not sure whether postscript getting generated or not.

Answer (score 0):

Does the template has embedded Fonts? Probably the merging doesn't combine those fonts. If you don't need embedded Fonts you could remove them. Adobe does some good work in combining embedded fonts.

If you want you can send me such a big pdf document, so that i can understand, why this file is getting so big. I am a developer of a PDF library and getting the smallest PDF is one interesting usecase i am working on.